# How to avoid Race Condition on Very Large Solution compilation?

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I am working with a very large solution ~790 projects compiling on Visual Studio 2022 17.6 on windows 10.
At several times compiling with msbuild Paralel Builds enabled (/mp) ihave error due to race condition

I am using binary log to view but cannot find the exact problem.

The error i get

```
928:3>CSC : error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\1Git\Bin\obj\GoldenCreatorService\Debug\GoldService.dll' for writing -- 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\1Git\Bin\obj\GoldenCreatorService\Debug\GoldService.dll' because it is being used by another process.' [C:\1Git\Bin\Sources\processing\GoldenCreatorService\GoldenCreatorService.csproj]
```

After checking the binary log i have seen the following :
Under "Evaluation" i see 2 entries for the same projects
[image]

The projects which create the exception `928:3>CSC : error CS2012: Cannot open` is always different.
Trying to compile inside visual studio does not create the error.
Compile with single thread works without error.

CopyLocal is disabled.

I cannot share the full code - i am looking for a way to avoid or identify the root cause .

Comment: Is it possible that `GoldenCreatorService` is being built for multiple platforms? Each unique Configuration and Platform pair is handled as a separate project build.

Comment: It builds for other platforms - using a post build event. Other projects are the same but are not shown double on the evaluation list.

Comment: Your situation may not be easy to investigate. This may also be related to the hardware. Have you specified a value that exceeds the computer processor? Also try setting -verbosity to see the build verbosity less.

Comment: Using more then 16 cores always get this error - i am working on a 64 Core computer. Using the binary log replay option i have access to the detailed verbosity - i still cannot track the exact project. The main concern is why i am not seeing twice other projects on teh evaluation list ?